# Vibrate android using fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to use the vibrate utility on one of my fragments when a person touches one of the radio buttons for selection.  I have used this tool before `public class Utility extends Activity` and it worked using it on my MainActivity vice a Fragment.

I import `import android.os.Vibrator;` into my fragment (called Fragment_Bread) and declare it as 
`private Fragment_Bread activity = this`;

Everything works fine except now when I save everything my Utility class has an error inside it `.getSystemService`

I hover over it and get the following error "The method getSystemService(String) is undefined for the type Fragment_Bread"

I following the recommended fix "Create method getSystemService(String) in type Fragment_Bread

This creates the following in my Fragment_Bread

```
public Vibrator getSystemService(String vibratorService) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
```

All is well with no errors except when I run it, the application crashes.

I am new at programming on both android and java so any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Fragment_Bread that I wrote:

```
package com.example.fragmentsandwich;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;

public class Fragment_Bread extends Fragment {

    TextView section_label1;
    Communicator comm;
    Button submit_bread_button;
    RadioGroup breadRadioGroup;
    private Fragment_Bread activity = this;

    // Bread
    RadioButton white_button, wheat_button, rye_button, whole_grain_button,
            flat_button;
    RadioButton wrap_button, sour_dough_button, bagel_button;

    public Fragment_Bread() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bread, container,
                false);

        return rootView;
    }


    OnCheckedChangeListener listen = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            Utility.vibrate(activity);
            String bread = "";

            if (white_button.isChecked()) {
                bread = "White";
            }

            if (wheat_button.isChecked()) {
                bread = "Wheat";
            }

            if (rye_button.isChecked()) {
                bread = "Rye";
            }

            if (whole_grain_button.isChecked()) {
                bread = "Whole grain";
            }

            if (flat_button.isChecked()) {
                bread = "Flat";
            }

            if (wrap_button.isChecked()) {
                bread = "Wrap";
            }

            if (sour_dough_button.isChecked()) {
                bread = "Sour dough";
            }

            comm.update_bread(bread);

        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        comm = (Communicator) getActivity();
        white_button = (RadioButton) getActivity().findViewById(
                R.id.white_button);
        wheat_button = (RadioButton) getActivity().findViewById(
                R.id.wheat_button);
        rye_button = (RadioButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.rye_button);
        whole_grain_button = (RadioButton) getActivity().findViewById(
                R.id.whole_grain_button);
        flat_button = (RadioButton) getActivity()
                .findViewById(R.id.flat_button);
        wrap_button = (RadioButton) getActivity() 
                .findViewById(R.id.wrap_button);
        sour_dough_button = (RadioButton) getActivity().findViewById(
                R.id.sour_dough_button);

        //white_button.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listen);

        breadRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.breadRadioGroup);
        for(int i = 0; i < breadRadioGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
            RadioButton radio_button = (RadioButton) breadRadioGroup.getChildAt(i);
            radio_button.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listen);
        }

    }

    public Vibrator getSystemService(String vibratorService) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }


}
```

Utility Class that I wrote:

```
package com.example.fragmentsandwich;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Vibrator;

public class Utility extends Fragment_Bread {

public static void vibrate(Fragment_Bread activity) {

    Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) activity.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    vibrator.vibrate(50);

} //END VIBRATE

} //END UTILITY
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that Fragment_Bread extends from Fragment.

The Fragment class does not have a getSystemService() method. Instead you can call getActivity() on your Fragment and call the method from there.

```
public static void vibrate(Fragment_Bread fragment) {
    Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) fragment.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    vibrator.vibrate(50);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem may be in this line.

```
private Fragment_Bread activity = this;
```

you should use

```
Utility.vibrate(getActivity());
```

instead.
Happy 2 Help.